# Why can't I authenticate a user using LinkedIn's Android SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, linkedin-api

I've registered my app with a developer account.  I added my debug hash key to the account.  I'm attempting to authenticate this way:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    // Store a reference to the current activity 
    final Activity thisActivity = this;

    LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).init(thisActivity, buildScope(), new AuthListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthSuccess() {
            // Authentication was successful.  You can now do
            // other calls with the SDK.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
            // Handle authentication errors
        }
    }, true);
}
```

}

```
// Build the list of member permissions our LinkedIn session requires
private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.W_SHARE);
}
```

The LinkedIn app will appear then immediately close...no "Do you want to let this app do things?" dialog.  What is more, niether `onAuthSuccess()` or `onAuthError()` are fired.  How could this be?  My code is pretty identical to their sample app.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the LIAuthError to the logcat or inspect logcat for any useful information?

Comment: There is no error. `onAuthError()` doesn't get triggered. And there's no logs.